# JSON Array can not be converted to JSON Object in Android

Tags: java, android, json, phpmyadmin

I want to populate spinner from JSON .I have print response properly on log cat.but not fetch in Spinner .Here is my json format

**JSON :**

```
[
    {
        "cat_id": "1",
        "cat_code": "ELEC1",
        "cat_name": "Electronics",
        "cat_created_date": "2014-08-28",
        "cat_isactive": "Y",
        "cat_updated_date": "0000-00-00"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "2",
        "cat_code": "Decor1",
        "cat_name": "Decor",
        "cat_created_date": "0000-00-00",
        "cat_isactive": "Y",
        "cat_updated_date": "0000-00-00"
    }
]
```

I want to display cat_name in Spinner.
But I m getting JSONException
Can some one help me how to this.

Here is my cod

```
    public class Customer_Order_Detail extends Activity
{
    private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Spinner spinnerCategory;

    // Url to get all categories
    private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://192.168.1.102/client_vendor_mgmt/category.php";


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customer_order);
        categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();
        spinnerCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
        new GetCategories().execute();


    }

    /**
     * Adding spinner data
     * */
    private void populateSpinner() {
        List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++)
        {
            lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
        }

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerCategory.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    }


    /*
     * Async task to get all  categories
     */

    private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Customer_Order_Detail.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Fetching categories..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.e("Response: ", " > " + json);


            if (json != null) {
                try
                {


                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

                    if (jsonObj != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray categories = jsonObj.getJSONArray("category_master");                     

                        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                            Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("cat_id"),catObj.getString("cat_code"));
                            categoriesList.add(cat);
                        }
                    }

                } 
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            populateSpinner();
        }

    }


}

Here is my log cat info


08-30 13:11:02.453: E/Response:(640):  > 
08-30 13:11:02.453: E/Response:(640): [{"cat_id":"1","cat_code":"ELEC1","cat_name":"Electronics","cat_created_date":"2014-08-28","cat_isactive":"Y","cat_updated_date":"0000-00-00"},{"cat_id":"2","cat_code":"Decor1","cat_name":"Decor","cat_created_date":"0000-00-00","cat_isactive":"Y","cat_updated_date":"0000-00-00"}]
08-30 13:11:02.563: W/System.err(640): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"cat_created_date":"2014-08-28","cat_code":"ELEC1","cat_id":"1","cat_updated_date":"0000-00-00","cat_isactive":"Y","cat_name":"Electronics"},{"cat_created_date":"0000-00-00","cat_code":"Decor1","cat_id":"2","cat_updated_date":"0000-00-00","cat_isactive":"Y","cat_name":"Decor"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-30 13:11:02.563: W/System.err(640):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
08-30 13:11:02.563: W/System.err(640):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
08-30 13:11:02.573: W/System.err(640):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
08-30 13:11:02.573: W/System.err(640):  at com.customer.demo.Customer_Order_Detail$GetCategories.doInBackground(Customer_Order_Detail.java:98)
08-30 13:11:02.623: W/System.err(640):  at com.customer.demo.Customer_Order_Detail$GetCategories.doInBackground(Customer_Order_Detail.java:1)
08-30 13:11:02.623: W/System.err(640):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-30 13:11:02.623: W/System.err(640):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-30 13:11:02.623: W/System.err(640):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-30 13:11:02.633: W/System.err(640):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-30 13:11:02.633: W/System.err(640):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-30 13:11:02.633: W/System.err(640):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: You have not pasted the complete json as category_master key is not showing in your given json.

Comment: you have posted JSONArray and you are parsing as JSONObject so its gives error

Comment: post the entire json responce

Comment: Error is just as it reads.. when posting questions make sure to only include the *relevant* code.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json); this is json object and u have JsonArray create methed that take jsonArray in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is *just* as it reads. The *root value is a JSON Array* (not a JSON Object). Thus the code should then use JSONArray and not JSONObject;

```
JSONArray categories = new JSONArray(json);
```

And then loop over the JSONArray (of categories) as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

you have posted JSONArray and you are parsing as JSONObject so its gives error So try this

```
JSONArray categories = new JSONArray(json);  
JSONObject catObj = new JSONObject();               

 for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++){
  catObj = categories.get(i);
  Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("cat_id"),
                              catObj.getString("cat_code"));

  categoriesList.add(cat);
 }
```